# Azure Web App Rewrite rule not working properly because of Output caching

Tags: node.js, caching, iis, azure-web-app-service, http-redirect

I have a Azure node web app. Web.config taken from [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Using-a-custom-web.config-for-Node-apps)

I have a http -> https redirection rule in web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <configuration>
      <system.webServer>
         <handlers>
             <add name="iisnode" path="server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
         </handlers>
         <rewrite>
             <rules>
                 <rule name="Force HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)"/>
                        <conditions>
                           <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" /> 
                        </conditions>
                        <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST} 
                                {REQUEST_URI}" appendQueryString="false" 
                                redirectType="Permanent" />
                 </rule>
                 <rule name="StaticContent">
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="public{REQUEST_URI}" />
                 </rule>
                 <rule name="DynamicContent">
                    <conditions>
                       <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile"  
                                                       negate="True" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="server.js" />
                 </rule>
          </rules>
      </rewrite>
     </system.webServer>
 </configuration>
```

After the server restarts `http://site/index.html -> https://site/index.html` works, but on quick subsequent request `http://site/index.html` just serves the cached output (client caching is disabled). Though, redirection starts working after short period of inactivity but problem re-occurs.

Disabling output cache as below solves the problem (Output cache is enabled by default and for solution disabling enableKernelCache is enough)

```
<system.webServer>
    <caching enable="false" enableKernelCache="false" />
```

It seems like Output cache is sending the response before hitting the rewrite rules.

Has anyone encountered the same problem? Is this the optimal solution (or if any) or is there any performance setback with this solution (the [link](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/managing-performance-settings/walkthrough-iis-output-caching) says output caching targets semi-dynamic content)?

Note** Couldn't reproduce locally

**EDIT**:

The following website is a sample setup where this problem occurs.
Project setup

```
wwwroot
-- web.config (above)
-- server.js
-- public
   -- index.html
   -- main.css
```

Server.js

```
var http = require('http');
function handleRequest(request, response){
   response.end('It Works!! Path Hit: ' + request.url);
}
var server = http.createServer(handleRequest);
var port = process.env.PORT || "80";
server.listen(port, "0.0.0.0", 511, function(){
   console.log("Server listening on: http://localhost:%s", port);
});
```

After `David Ebbo` comments below I used curl and to my wonder it worked meanwhile it was not working in the browser. So it got me thinking and after playing with some headers( I looked up what headers browser is sending) I can reproduce it in curl too. When making curl request with `Accept-encoding: gzip` curl also doesn't redirect. (It might be hard to reproduce this just making curl request with the header. Try the curl command when it fails in the browser)

[image]

After reading up [here](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httpcompression), it seems like compression for dynamic content is done everytime while not for the static content. And it seems true cause 
`http://test-redirect.azurewebsites.net` (which is a dynamic endpoint) always redirects

But, doing this does not solve the problem

```
<urlCompression doStaticCompression="false" doDynamicCompression="true" />
```

Instead now curl without header can reproduce the problem

Comment: To isolate from browser behavior, does that repro if you use curl to request the http URL? I was not able to repro this in my test Azure Web App.

Comment: Also, to isolate from anything else your site may be doing, can you repro with a trivial site that only contains this web.config and a simple index,html?

Comment: @DavidEbbo please see the edit

Comment: I can't seem to repro what you see. When I run `curl -H "Accept-encoding:gzip" http://test-redirect.azurewebsites.net/`, I consistently get the redirect to https. Not sure what the difference is.

Comment: @DavidEbbo please try `http://test-redirect.azurewebsites.net/index.html`. `http://test-redirect.azurewebsites.net` is a dynamic endpoint which do get redirected. Problem lies with the redirection of `html` files. For ex. `http://test-redirect.azurewebsites.net/main.css` is also getting redirected. Also, please try the link in  browser first. It seems that once it stops redirecting from browser then only the `curl -H` will stop redirecting.

Comment: Ah yes, I do repro with this URL! Now to figure out what's going on... :)

Comment: Darn, it seems the repro comes and go. Earlier, I saw `curl -H "Accept-encoding:gzip" http://test-redirect.azurewebsites.net/index.html` return the gzipped content, but now it's correctly redirecting. I don't get it...

Comment: Ok, the way to repro consistently is to first request https: `curl -H "Accept-encoding:gzip" https://test-redirect.azurewebsites.net/index.html`, and then http `curl -H "Accept-encoding:gzip" http://test-redirect.azurewebsites.net/index.html`. That consistently gets it in the bad state.

Comment: Yes and seems like disabling cache `<caching enable="false" enableKernelCache="false" />` makes it work or by just requesting the url with cache busting `http://test-redirect.azurewebsites.net/index.html?v=1`. My guess is it has to do something with `static compression` as mentioned [here](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httpcompression). Not sure if disabling the cache is the best way to go

Comment: My guess is that it is a general IIS thing and probably not specific to Azure Web Apps. But beyond that, I'm afraid I can't explain it :(